# inexplicable behaviour of activity backstack

Tags: android, android-activity, back-stack, onbackpressed

I have simple app with two activities. Here is manifest:

```
<application>
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityA"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Map">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityB"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:host="https://stackoverflow.com/"
                      android:scheme="http"
                      android:pathPrefix="/questions/ask"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</>
```

as u can see, when link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" will be clicked - my app will open second activity.
In the ActivityB I override onBackPressed method:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(isTaskRoot){
                startActivity(Intent(this, MapActivity::class.java))
                finish()
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed()
            }
    }
```

so when second activity started from link and I click on back btn, ActivityA is opened and ActivityB is finished.

for the first look everything looks fine, but if after this i press home btn, and then relaunch app from stack - ActivityB is opened again instead ActivityA.

Please explain me why it happen and how to fix this issue. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
after onBackPressed in ActivityB, ActivityA is opened, and then i click onBackBtn instead HomeBtn, so app is closed. in this case after relaunch from stack ActivityB is opened.

Answer (score 0):

When you press the home btn in `ActivityB`, Android calls the `onPause()` method on activity lifecycle, and in this moment your app is paused on activityB. It are not destroyed like you did overriding `onBackPressed()`. So when you relaunch your app again, the SO will be call `onResume()` on `ActivityB` that is in backstack. 
To change this behavior, you have to override the `onPause()` method on finish the activity manually.

Comment: I press homeBtn in ActivityA after I leave ActivityB with onBackPressed

Comment: I see, try to call finish method in `else` as well `else { finish() }`

Comment: it wouldn't help, because isTaskRoot = true, so else method wouldn't call